# NoMethodError - Private method 'my_stats' called ... in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails Console has been working fine until now. Suddenly I cannot call methods, neither class methods nor instance methods. But the app works fine.

```
Rails console
Catalog.my_stats    
NoMethodError (private method `my_stats' called for #<Catalog:0x0000560a3796c9a8>)
```

If I try a method that does not exist it says "undefined method" instead of "private method", so it is able to see that the method exists. However - the method is NOT defined as private, and it has been working fine before. Built in Catalog.all works fine. Running on Ubuntu.

Example code for catalog.rb

```
def self.my_stats
  puts "Hello!"
end
```

**Update**
I have another function in catalog.rb called string_to_array. This function responds well. And I can change it to a class function, and it works without problem. But if I create new functions they don't respond... also other, older functions responds well. Weird.

Comment: Can you share Model file code for `my_stats`?

Comment: Just tried some dummy text like this, but does not work. Byebug does not trigger either... so it seems to give up before the function. 

def self.my_stats 
    puts "My stats"
end

Also tried the instance method without self, but does not work either.

Comment: Is the word `private` anywhere in the model file? Does this happen for all classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**
The file had one "end" too much

**Long answer** I discovered that one of the functions above the troublesome ones had one "end" too much. Thanks to VS Code's vertical stripes I could identify that this particular "end" closed the class definition. This is why the functions were considered private, even without the word "private", because Rails gladly allowed them to be defined outside of the class. So the syntax checker did not consider this as an error. I also tried to add a lot of "end" words in the middle of the file, and in the end of the file, but the syntax was considered valid, still. This also explains why the GUI still worked, but the console had trouble accessing indirect "private" functions... maybe someone has a better name for these.. but now I've but them all inside the class where I think they belong. Thanks for your inputs.

**Footnote**
The stats code was tested temporarily in a particular branch that matched a spesific customer. The customer pasted this code into the catalog.rb file himself as a quick addon feature, and it worked for both of us. I then wanted this same code to be part of a new branch / version that was already in progress. I must have pasted it wrong, so that I did not get a fully functional checked-in version at my side - until now. Thats some time ago. So the "worked before - not now" was a little more tricky this time.